# Variable Assignment in basic 1-10 counter

Tags: javascript

Here is a very basic counter to 10:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log (i); // outputs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
}

console.log(i);
```

I would expect the value of i in global space to be 10.  It is 11.  The only reason I can think of is that it is assigned 11 to break the loop i <= 10.

Is that the correct reason?

Comment: Yes it is. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `for` loops work in this fashion:

```
for (/*initial conditions set at beginning of loop*/; 
     /*break condition checked before entering the loop each time*/; 
     /*command to execute at the end of each loop*/) 
{
    // stuff to do during loop
}
```

So your assumption is correct, the for loop runs until `i = 11` because that is the first time the loop has reached the break condition.

For loops were created to avoid repetitive while or do/while loops.  The above loop can be thought of as:

```
/*initial conditions set at beginning of loop*/
while (/*break condition checked before entering the loop each time*/){
     // stuff to do during loop
     /*command to execute at the end of each loop*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop of the form:

```
for (<inits>; <tests>; <repeats>) {
    <body>;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
<inits>;
while (<tests>) {
    <body>;
    <repeats>;
}
```

On the last iteration of the loop, `i++` will be executed to set `i` to 11. Then when it returns to the top of the loop, the test `i <= 10` will be executed. Since this is false, the loop terminates. At this point, `i` is still 11.